# How do I print a horizontal list vertically? More info down below

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So, for the last couple months I'm doing this course on Udacity.com named- CS101. After, finishing it to 53% I was presented with the question that asked me to write an algorithm to very a simple sudoku puzzle. Thus, as far as my expertise goes and the way I have designed the algorithm, I would want to make a list print vertically.

For example:

```
[[4,7,3],[1,8,2],[3,9,3]]
```

I would want the above list to print out as

```
[[4,1,3],[7,8,9],[3,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) which aggregates together all ith-element of each given list :

```
values = [[4,7,3],[1,8,2],[3,9,3]]
values = list(zip(*values))
print(values) # [(4, 1, 3), (7, 8, 9), (3, 2, 3)]
```

Using loops:

```
result = [[] for _ in range(len(values[0]))]
for value in values:
    for jdx, val in enumerate(value):
        result[jdx].append(val)
print(result)
```

Comment: I would want a more basic version as the course doesn't go that far yet! thank you. maybe a for loop is possible. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) here.

```
lst=[[4,7,3],[1,8,2],[3,9,3]]
print(list(zip(*lst)))
# [(4, 1, 3), (7, 8, 9), (3, 2, 3)]
```

If you want list of lists

```
list(map(list,zip(*lst)))
# [[4, 1, 3], [7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: I would want a more basic version as the course doesn't go that far yet! thank you. maybe a for loop is possible. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode for you to write in python:

```
for column in matrix
  for item in column
    print item
```

Worded another way:

```
for c from 0 to #cols
  for r from 0 to #rows
    print matrix[r][c]
```

Comment: Sorry this is not what the OP is expected ;) Also you may not give pseudocode when the solution is easy  ;)

Comment: The goal is to grant copy+paste code instead of a guide on how to write a simple algorithm? My answer is generic to programming instead of specific to python because this is fundamental

Comment: I would want a more basic version as the course doesn't go that far yet! thank you. maybe a for loop is possible. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you want the transpose of your list of lists, you could use the built-in function `map` with `zip`:

```
l = [[4,7,3],[1,8,2],[3,9,3]]

list(map(list, zip(*l)))
```

output:

```
[[4, 1, 3], [7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 3]]
```

if you are familiar with [numpy](https://numpy.org/) you can use:

```
import numpy as np

np.array(l).T.tolist()
```

output:

```
[[4, 1, 3], [7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 3]]
```

if you want to use `for` loops:

```
len_cols = len(l[0])
len_rows = len(l)

transpose = [[None] * len_rows for _ in range(len_cols)]

for i in range(len_row):
    for j in range(len_cols):
        transpose[j][i] = l[i][j]
```

output:

```
[[4, 1, 3], [7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: I would want a more basic version as the course doesn't go that far yet! thank you. maybe a for loop is possible. thank you.

Comment: Sir, I'm extremely sorry to bother you. But can you explain me the algorithm a little bit. Thank you.

Comment: you can see your list of list as a matrix, where the number of lists is the number of rows and the number of elements in an inner list is the number of columns, first I create the shape of the transpose and then I fill with the actual values, In a transpose, the rows become the columns and the columns become the rows

Answer (score 0):

```
def transpose(lst): 
    transpose_list =[[row[i] for row in lst] for i in range(len(lst[0]))] 
    return transpose_list 

lst = [[4,7,3],[1,8,2],[3,9,3]]
print(transpose(lst))
```

**Output:**

```
[[4, 1, 3], [7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 3]]
```

**Same as:**

```
tr_lst = []
for i in range(len(lst[0])):
    row_elem = []
    for row in lst:
        row_elem.append(row[i])
    tr_lst.append(row_elem)
print(tr_lst)
```

**Algorithm:**
Lets take an example:

```
[[4,7,3],[1,8,2],[3,9,3]]
```

1)

```
for row in lst:
```

1st I will iterate over all the rows `[4,7,3], [1,8,2], [3,9,3]` (there are three rows)

Then I will take 1st element from each row and append them into a `list(row_elem)` --> `[4,1,3]` which will get appended to the `tr_list`

then will take 2nd element from each row --> `[7, 8, 9]` which will also get appended to tr_list and then third element --> `[3, 2, 3]`

By using `for i in range(len(lst[0])):`
I am accesing the ith element.

---

### Edit:

#### first iteration of `for i in range(len(lst[0])):`

```
row1: [4,7,3]
row2: [1,8,2]
row3: [3,9,3]
```

---

These **`<num>`** numbers will get appended to the `row_elem` list
now the `row_elem` will have `[4, 1, 3]`
I will append this results(`row_elem`) into `tr_list`

`tr_list` will be right now `[[4, 1, 3]]`

#### second iteration:

```
row1: [4,7,3]
row2: [1,8,2]
row3: [3,9,3]
```

`row_elem` will be now `[7,8,9]` which will get appended to `tr_list`

`tr_list` will be `[[4, 1, 3], [7, 8, 9]]`

similarly, for the third iteration, you will do it.

```
row1: [4,7,3]
row2: [1,8,2]
row3: [3,9,3]
```

`row_elem` will be now `[3,2,3]` which will get appended to `tr_list`

`tr_list` will be `[[4, 1, 3], [7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 3]]`

Comment: Sir I appreciate your help. But can I get an explanation on how this algorithm is working? thank you and sorry for the burden.

Comment: thanks you so much. I really appreciate the time and effort you put into it. Btw can I communicate with you somehow. I wanted to ask you something. Any like social media links or anything?

Comment: Yes go ahead you can find the way to contact in my profile.